# Button Click to display the API data on screen using array of objects

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch the API data results not on the console but on the screen itself on a button click. I was able to do that using UseEffect without using a button .. but I am being unable to do that with the button. The error it gives me on this code is something like this:

```
"TypeError: items.map is not a function"
```

and when I try to use simple string on the usestate like `Usestate('')` and then do my code it gives me an error like this:

```
"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {results, info}).
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
```

I don't even understand the error as I am new to react. Is it because I am using axios? and not fetch.. How can I get it on the screen?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function Things() {
const [items, setItems] = useState([])


function fetchRandomData() {
    axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').then(
        (response) => {
            setItems(response.data)
        }
    );
 }
 return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={fetchRandomData}>Fetch Random Data</button>
      <div>
      {items.map(item => (
      <li key={item.status}>{item.data.results}</li>
    ))};
      </div>
      
     
     




        
    </div>
    );
    };
   export default Things
```

Comment: Try to introduce boolean variable initialize it with false then onClick event set it to true. Use **useEffect() {  if(shouldFetch) then your API request }**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current Axios request and state update, you are getting the following object:

[image]

which is not iterable, that's why you are getting that error.

To make your code work perfectly, we have to update the state with

`setItems(response.data.results);`

[image]

Which is an `Array`(See above image) and in this case, you can use the `map` method without any problem.

Just be careful while accessing the data from items, and use proper keys.

Final Output:

[image]

Here is how you can list render the data correctly:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Things() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  function fetchRandomData() {
    console.log("asodsb");
    axios
      .get("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then(response => {
        setItems(response.data.results);
        console.log(response.data.results);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={fetchRandomData}>Fetch Random Data</button>
      <div>
        {items && items.map(item => (
          <>
            <img src={item.picture.thumbnail} />
            <p>First Name: {item.name.first}</p>
            <p>Last Name: {item.name.last}</p>
            <p>Phone: {item.cell}</p>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Things;
```

Full Working code: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pcynxm)

Comment: Hey thankyou very much man.. much appreciated.. :D

Comment: Hey but why did you use items && items.. wouldn't just one items work?

Comment: && means, if ```items``` is not empty then run that ```items.map(...``` part else do nothing.

Comment: OO ahaha its simple and operator.. I thought it was something else.. anyways thanks man...

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you one last time but inside the map method.. I did something like this...  {items && items.map(item => (
          <>
          <p>All info: {item.data.results}</p>
          </>
        ))}  I wanted to show the junk of all the data on the screen and not like yk properly but shows error saying results not defined .. when there definitely is results inside data..

Comment: just use ```<p>All info: {JSON.stringify(item)}</p>```

Comment: Thanks mann.. Looking forward from hearing your other amazing answers as I guess Ill be asking a lot of react questions lol

Comment: :) Happy Coding,